# How to create a div that is sticky, floats on top of other elements, and scales with screen

Tags: html, css

I am developing a notification system for a website, and the notification is to pop up at the top centre of the screen and be sticky without any hardcoding (which I have done), but I am struggling to make it float on top of other elements. Currently, it moves all elements below it lower by a block. I played around with it but just can't figure out a solution or whether it is actually possible. I am using the "notification-panel" for positioning.

I tried to use float but it only moves it left or right. It won't allow me to centre it.

HTML:

```
<div id="notification-panel" style="display: none">
    <div id="notification-saving-panel" style="display: none">
        <label id="notification-saving-icon">&#9729;</label>
        <label id="notification-saving-message">Saving...</label>
    </div>

    <label id="notification-message"></label>
    <button id="notification-confirmation-button">Ok</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#notification-panel
{
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid;
    border-right-width: 2px;
    border-left-width: 2px;
    display: block;
    left: 42%;
    margin: 1%;
    position: sticky;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 15%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `position:absolute`?

Comment: I didn't think that it would work as I need the item to be sticky relative to the screen, not to the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a small example of a fixed item above all layers.

Using position fixed so it doesn't move when scrolling and z-index so it's above all other layers.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px; /* Height of the bar */
}

.notification {
  position: fixed; /* so it's sticks when scrolling */ 
  z-index: 10; /* layer number */
  top: 0; /* position */
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fbfbf0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px; /* don't use in production */
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="notification">Wow!</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a metus sagittis, molestie nulla sit amet, bibendum lectus. Proin consequat enim nec feugiat finibus. In non quam ut nunc laoreet tempus at aliquet nunc. Nunc sapien mi, sollicitudin eu fringilla sed, dictum id mi. Sed egestas purus justo, id vulputate massa cursus vel. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin pretium iaculis lorem, ut dapibus augue.

Donec elementum lacinia finibus. Curabitur sed mattis purus. Fusce non quam consequat, fringilla diam et, commodo nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Nam rutrum justo facilisis orci interdum auctor. Nulla id finibus felis. Integer vehicula aliquet consectetur. Nunc mattis congue bibendum. Quisque rhoncus leo vitae feugiat volutpat. Quisque maximus egestas ex, quis ullamcorper leo fermentum eget. Integer aliquet turpis dolor. Donec et dapibus leo. Etiam malesuada ac felis in pharetra. Vestibulum in gravida metus, tincidunt feugiat augue. Aliquam ullamcorper fringilla mauris eu pretium.

Phasellus cursus dapibus lorem at porttitor. Curabitur euismod lectus lacus, et sagittis diam bibendum vitae. Morbi iaculis aliquam enim quis mollis. Mauris at interdum nisl. Praesent dictum, justo at elementum viverra, nulla odio elementum felis, a congue dolor ante id tellus. Nunc ullamcorper neque a turpis venenatis, et tristique augue auctor. Quisque fringilla nisi ut arcu auctor, sed facilisis turpis ultrices. Proin tincidunt, sem a sagittis pulvinar, lectus nisl laoreet purus, eu tristique ligula turpis vel massa. Aliquam interdum vestibulum elementum. Aenean at elit justo. Curabitur sit amet leo ac nibh imperdiet sodales at nec felis. Quisque eu libero pharetra, interdum lectus et, luctus magna. Donec nec nisi imperdiet, eleifend ligula et, cursus mauris.

Fusce quam justo, aliquam sit amet magna non, blandit commodo ligula. Etiam elementum dolor eget leo luctus, efficitur semper ex tincidunt. Integer at nibh risus. Aenean posuere, eros vulputate vehicula sodales, velit nulla egestas enim, quis vestibulum nisi metus laoreet sem. Sed lacinia orci vel lacinia porttitor. Praesent id suscipit arcu, et dignissim eros. Donec ut faucibus enim, ut porttitor libero. Vivamus quis enim felis. Etiam rhoncus justo tellus, non placerat quam consectetur non. Ut vestibulum ultrices justo. Cras metus tortor, dictum non erat ut, eleifend rutrum sem. Sed vitae varius dui. Nullam non maximus quam, ac bibendum ex. Pellentesque eleifend elit et dignissim feugiat.

Phasellus a tristique dui, quis cursus nulla. Cras hendrerit tortor eu lacinia convallis. Nulla hendrerit egestas purus, sed pharetra felis dignissim non. Vestibulum est nulla, semper ut nunc ac, sagittis aliquam est. Cras aliquam varius gravida. Praesent ut posuere leo, in porttitor leo. Vivamus bibendum magna metus, at viverra diam tincidunt sit amet. Nam vel posuere ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ullamcorper quam nisi, et interdum nisi gravida id.
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that the solution was so simple as changing "sticky" to "fixed".

Comment: CSS is magical :-) Sticky is also useful in it's own way. https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/.